# Use a Level of Detail Expression in Tablaeu on 1 of 2 forms of a date variable

Tags: date, tableau-api

In Tableau a Level of Detail Expression allows you to create a calculated variable that is affected by none or only some of the view level filters.

I have a view that has 2 filters based on the same column -- a YEAR(Date) filter and a MONTH(Date) filter.

If my Level of Detail Expression is:

```
{EXCLUDE [Date mdy]: SUM([count.Attrition])}
```

that won't work because it would remove both date filters. I only want to remove the MONTH date filter.

However, this

```
{EXCLUDE [MONTH(Date mdy)]: SUM([count.Attrition])}
```

is an invalid expression and this:

```
{EXCLUDE MONTH([Date mdy]): SUM([count.Attrition])}
```

is allegedly valid but doesn't actually work.

Comment: What version of Tableau are you using? Are you sure your Date fields are on the filter shelf? Or on another shelf? If they are only on the filter shelf, then there is no reason to exclude them -- and it will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

**Hack-R**, how about using FIXED, I think that should help solve this:

```
{FIXED [Year] : SUM([count.Attrition]) }
```

Using FIXED is basically forcing Tableau to calculate aggregate measure at specific level - in this case on Year

**[Year]** is just a simple calculated field which returns Year value.

```
YEAR([Date mdy])
```

Creating a dedicated calculated field is probably not really necessary in Tableau 10, but it's just my personal preference to keep things organized.

You might be wonder why *EXCLUDE* didn't work - I think the main use-case is different with INCLUDE/EXCLUDE and probably best explained in this (a bit lengthly) [article](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/1/lods-fun-jedi-filters-48123?hootPostID=dc31f7597abdc58f8046c27e768cd2ba).

Hope this helps.